# Video muted by default / Enable audio on fullscreen view only

Tags: video.js

I read the entire API and dozens of related help topics but I dont manage to get with the code to help me do what I want.

**This is what I need:
The video is muted by default. 
When user click on fullscreen button the video is played with full volume.**

How do I code this?

I understand I can mute my video adding myPlayer.volume(0) like this:

```
<script>
  var myPlayer = _V_("video_1");
  myPlayer.volume(0);
</script>
```

But how do I detect whether the video is in fullscreen or not?
I found the fullscreenchange event on the API but dont manage to implement it successfully. Any help will do my day. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen for the *fullscreenchange* event and check the `isFullScreen` property of the player.

```
var myPlayer = _V_("video_1");
myPlayer.volume(0);
var onFullScreen = function(){
  if (this.isFullScreen) {
    this.volume(1);
  } else {
    this.volume(0);
  }
};
myPlayer.addEvent("fullscreenchange", onFullScreen);
```

https://github.com/zencoder/video-js/blob/master/docs/api.md